# Is the ServiceBehaviour's namespace important for web service versioning?

Tags: wcf, web-services, namespaces, versioning, servicebehavior

Simple, as that... is the `ServiceBehaviour`'s namespace important for web service versioning? Meaning that for forward/backward compatibility of clients to server is this namespace involved in any way?

I really didn't understand what is this specific namespace and its use. Could anybody enlighting me about this?

Thank you!

**EDIT1**: After my investigations this namespace appears in WSDL here in the first line: `<wsdl:definitions name="SvcTest" targetNamespace="api.company.com/Services/Tester">` ...but I don't see if this would influence or not the versioning... maybe I am blind or miss something. Or maybe I am too worried... why would I add some date here (`<wsdl:definitions name="SvcTest" targetNamespace="api.company.com/Services/Tester/2012/01">`) ?

**EDIT2**: I found this link, but is pointing to another location which is not available anymore: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/66c19783-6675-4bd7-83c1-2140d00a943e . Could anyone help?

Comment: I agree it is rude to downvote without leaving any comment

Comment: Thanks for your sympathy hugh :)

Comment: Why not try changing the namespace and see if this changes the resulting WSDL? Be sure to use wsHttpBinding to maximize the complexity of the WSDL (to give a larger set of elements to possibly be changed by changing the namespace).

Comment: @John thanks for your suggestions... I need to keep it to basicHttpBinding for now, as about how this affects the WSDL, I noticed only this first line where it appears: '<wsdl:definitions name="SvcTest" targetNamespace="http://api.company.com/Services/Tester">'

Comment: I meant changing the binding as part of the experiment. BTW, the target namespace affects _everything_ in the WSDL. Anything with `name="x"` is really "x in _targetNamespace_"

Comment: Maybe I am worried if I should have something like a date inside there as well or not. 'targetNamespace="api.company.com/Services/Tester/2010/01" '

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after some reading ...

Microsoft recommends using the namespace to version data contracts. See [Best Practices: Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx)

> Although in these examples names are changed (by appending a "2"), the recommendation is to change namespaces instead of names by appending new namespaces with a version number or a date. For example, the http://schemas.contoso.com/2005/05/21/PurchaseOrder data contract would change to the http://schemas.contoso.com/2005/10/14/PurchaseOrder data contract.

The namespace can be set in various places (ServiceContractAttribute,  ServiceBehaviorAttribute, DataContractAttribute, see [WCF service namespaces](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2010/11/10/WCF_service_namespaces)).

To have a consistent namespace in the WSDL and to keep track of changes to the contract, behavior or data contract it seems important.

Comment: although this is a good link, does not say anything about service behavior's namespace

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was a little too quick and did not fully read your question. I've editted the reply.

Comment: Yes, indeed it seems to be important, although is difficult to comprehend how exactly...